# JQuery Swap Color of a table cell

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a table cell as follows

```
<tr>
<td id = 'even'>row 8, cell 1</td>
<td  id = 'odd'>row 8, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

colors and font sizes are set using following css

```
 #even {    font-size : 10pt;    color : red;    background-color:yellow; }
 #odd {    font-size : 20pt;    color : white;    background-color:green; }
```

Now i want to swap the color of even and odd cells when a button is clicked

```
<button id='swapcolor' type="button" >Swap Colors</button>
```

font size also need to swap.

i have been trying to do it in this way

```
$("#swapcolor").click(function (e) {

      $('table #even').css('background-color','green');
      $('table #odd').css('background-color','yellow');

});

$("#swapfont").click(function () {
      $('#even').css("font-size", "20pt");
      $('#odd').css("font-size", "10pt");
});
```

my problem is how can i capture the current color of the cell

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use an overriding class rather than setting the CSS through JS itself. The following code will toggle a class for the `#even` and `#odd` tds

CSS

```
 #even {    font-size : 10pt;    color : red;    background-color:yellow; }
 #odd {    font-size : 20pt;    color : white;    background-color:green; }

 #even.swapColor {    background-green; }
 #odd.swapColor {    background-yellow; }
```

jQUERY

```
$("#swapcolor").click(function (e) {
      $('table #even, table #odd').toggleClass('swapColor');
});
```

Comment: I think font-size is being changed on click of different element

Answer (score 0):

`$('table #even').css('background-color')` returns the current color

Answer (score 0):

.css() can also be used as a getter method

```
var evenColor = $('table #even').css('background-color');
var oddColor = $('table #odd').css('background-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS classes instead of #IDs. And in jQuery check if the .odd class is present for the element. If so replace with .even class vice versa.